# AVCaptureStillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler inactive/invalid connection passed?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, image, avcapturesession

I am getting the above error. Can some please explain to me what this means and how to fix it? My code is below:

```
   UIButton *btn = (UIButton *)sender;
__weak UIButton *weakBtn = btn;
btn.enabled = NO;
    AVCaptureConnection *videoConnection = nil;
    for (AVCaptureConnection *connection in self.stillImageOutput.connections) {
        for (AVCaptureInputPort *port in [connection inputPorts]) {
            if ([[port mediaType] isEqual:AVMediaTypeVideo]) {
                videoConnection = connection;
                break;
            }
        }
        if (videoConnection) {
            break;
        }
    }

    [self.stillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:videoConnection completionHandler:^(CMSampleBufferRef imageSampleBuffer, NSError *error) {


        NSData *imageData = [AVCaptureStillImageOutput jpegStillImageNSDataRepresentation:imageSampleBuffer];
        UIImage *image = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:imageData];

        [self pushImagePreviewVCWithImage:image];
             // UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil);
        weakBtn.enabled = YES;
```

according to crashlytics it is breaking at if (videoConnection) { break; }

I've been trying to find a solution every where. I also found a tutorial with the same crash, but it wasn't fixed. http://www.musicalgeometry.com/?p=1297

thanks!

this is the error :

```
0  CoreFoundation                 0x00000001838602d8 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x000000019552c0e4 objc_exception_throw
2  AVFoundation                   0x00000001820c17a4 -[AVCaptureStillImageOutput captureStillImageAsynchronouslyFromConnection:completionHandler:]
3  First Derm                     0x000000010011fff4 -[CameraOverlayVC captureNow:] (CameraOverlayVC.m:124)
4  UIKit                          0x000000018830d398 -[UIApplication sendAction:to:from:forEvent:]
5  UIKit                          0x00000001882f6474 -[UIControl _sendActionsForEvents:withEvent:]
6  UIKit                          0x000000018830cd34 -[UIControl touchesEnded:withEvent:]
7  UIKit                          0x000000018830c9c0 -[UIWindow _sendTouchesForEvent:]
8  UIKit                          0x0000000188305efc -[UIWindow sendEvent:]
9  UIKit                          0x00000001882d9120 -[UIApplication sendEvent:]
10 UIKit                          0x000000018857a2b8 _UIApplicationHandleEventFromQueueEvent
11 UIKit                          0x00000001882d7634 _UIApplicationHandleEventQueue
12 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183818240 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE0_PERFORM_FUNCTION__
13 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001838174e4 __CFRunLoopDoSources0
14 CoreFoundation                 0x0000000183815594 __CFRunLoopRun
15 CoreFoundation                 0x00000001837412d4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
16 GraphicsServices               0x000000018d1976fc GSEventRunModal
17 UIKit                          0x000000018833ef40 UIApplicationMain
18 First Derm                     0x00000001000cbed8 main (main.m:14)
19 libdyld.dylib                  0x0000000195bd6a08 start
```

Comment: can you post the actual error/error log?

Comment: @0yeoj i edited above

Comment: ImageIO, CoreMedia and CoreVideo frameworks are all in your project? i think you missed some setup to `self.stillImageOutput`

Comment: @0yeoj which setup steps did i miss? Could you send me to a tutorial?

Comment: I dont know, i cant see your project but here's a [video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Xv1FfqVy-KM) tutorial quite detailed.

Answer (score 1):

This is how I do in my project, and it works well.

1. define custom serial queue to handle this in background
2. KVO pattern to observe the value.

you could reference my sample class:  https://github.com/htaiwan/CameraSnapShot